# If a triangle has two angles congruent, then two sides are congruent

Tags: geometry

If a triangle has two angles congruent, then two
sides are congruent.
How can this be proven without using ASA. I have been trying to solve this but I keep ending up having to use ASA. I was wondering if anyone had any idea how to do it.

Comment: What axioms/definitions *do* you want to use?

Comment: is it OK to use SAS?

Comment: @user7530 I can use any definitions/axioms. Just not ASA.

Comment: @Vasya yes  that would be okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)

$\frac {a}{sin A}=\frac {b}{sin B}=\frac {c}{sin C} = 2 R$

Answer (score 1):

Draw a median from vertex which is also a vertex of non-congruent angle. This median is also an altitude and you have two congruent triangles by SAS (half of the side, right angle and altitude which is a common side for both triangles).